# limit having binomial coefficients

Tags: limits

> $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\sum^{n}_{r=0}\binom{2n}{2r}\cdot 3^r}{\sum^{n-1}_{r=0}\binom{2n}{2r+1}\cdot 3^{r}}=$$

what i try

$$\sum^{n}_{r=0}\binom{2n}{2r}\cdot 3^{r}=(1+3)^{2n}=4^{2n}$$

$$\sum^{n-1}_{r=0}\binom{2n}{2r+1}\cdot 3^r=\frac{1}{3}\sum^{n-1}_{r=0}\binom{2n}{2r+1}\cdot 3^{r+1}$$

Did not know how i solve it Help me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the identities:

$$\frac{(1+\sqrt{x})^{2n}+(1-\sqrt{x})^{2n}}{2}=\sum_{k=0}^{n} {2n \choose 2k} x^k$$
$$\frac{(1+\sqrt{x})^{2n}-(1-\sqrt{x})^{2n}}{2\sqrt{x}}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {2n \choose 2k+1} x^k$$ Using $x=3$, we get the dnominator $D$ as
$$D=\frac{(4+2\sqrt{3})^n-(4-2\sqrt{3})^n}{2\sqrt{3}},$$ whereas the numerator $$N=\frac{(4+2\sqrt{3})^n+(4-2\sqrt{3})^n}{2},$$
$$L=\lim_{n \infty} \frac{\sqrt{3} (a^n+b^{n})}{(a^{n}-b^{n})}=\sqrt{3},$$
As $b/a<1$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(\frac{b}{a})^n=0$.